# Custom kryoSerialization flow not working in scala spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am new to scala.
I am trying to implement Custom kryo serialization.

In which I have two classes and one object :

**Operation**

```
package org.agg
object Operation {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var SparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Operation")
      .set("spark.io.compression.codec", "org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec")
      .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")
      .set("spark.kryo.registrator", "org.agg.KryoClass")

    var sc = new SparkContext(SparkConf)
    var sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc) 
    println("**********Operation***********")
  }
}
```

**KryoClass**

```
package org.agg
class KryoClass extends KryoRegistrator {
  def registerClasses(kryo: Kryo) {
    println("**********KryoClass***********")
    kryo.register(classOf[org.agg.KryoSerializeCode])
  } 
}
```

**KryoSerializeCode**

```
package org.agg
class KryoSerializeCode {
 println("**********KryoSerializeCode*************")
}
```

I am considering that In **Operation** Class If I am writing **set("spark.kryo.registrator", "org.agg.KryoClass")**
So this should call **KryoClass** and It will print **println("**********KryoClass***********")** statement in log file.

Command to execute **Operation** object is below:

> spark-submit --class org.agg.Operation  --master yarn --deploy-mode
>   cluster --num-executors 40 --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 3400m
>   --files /home/hive-site.xml --jars  /usr/iop/4.1.0.0/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/usr/iop/4.1.0.0/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/usr/iop/4.1.0.0/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar
>   /home/operation_jar.jar

But After executing this it is printing print statement in **Operation** class only not in **KryoClass** or **KryoSerializeCode** Class.

Do anyone having idea why it is not calling print statement inside **KryoClass** or **KryoSerializeCode** Class.

Comment: Execution of jar is successfull but output is only **"**********Operation***********"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark has the habit of doing things *lazily* - delaying unnecessary operations until they are actually needed. Seems like the creation of the Kryo serializer falls into that category - since you didn't actually *do* anything with your newly created `SparkContext`, Spark didn't bother creating the serializer.

If you add any Spark action to your `Operation.main`, e.g.:

```
sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3)).count()
```

You'll see the printouts you're expecting.

NOTE: you might have to register a few more classes, or disable `registrationRequired`

Comment: Thank you Tzach Zohar. I was looking for exact one.

Comment: It is calling print statement inisde **KryoClass** but not calling print statement inside **KryoSerializeCode** Class.

Comment: Of course not - because at no point are you creating an instance of `KryoSerializeCode` - this print you're expecting is part of its constructor, and _registering_ the class doesn't _construct_ an instance of it.

Comment: But as I am registering the class `kryo.register(classOf[org.agg.KryoSerializeCode])`

Comment: So it should call **KryoSerializeCode** class as well. I think

Comment: No, it shouldn't: there's no such thing as "it should _call_ class X", you can either _instantiate_ a class (which is done by calling `new KryoSerializeCode()`, not done in your code), which would trigger the constructor and print out the message; Or _reference_ the class using `classOf[org.agg.KryoSerializeCode]`, which is a _static_ reference (equivalent to Java's `KryoSerializeCode.class`), that does not create an instance and hence doesn't call constructor and doesn't print the message.

Comment: So as per my code If i call `new KryoSerializeCode()` in Operation class then all my code will participate in `custom serialization` criteria . correct ?

Comment: well, yeah... sort of: if you just call `new KryoSerializeCode()` and do nothing with the result - what good would that do?... it won't be _serialized_ because it won't be used... If you'll use `KryoSerializeCode` in an actual Spark operation (as part of your _data_, e.g. `sc.parallelize(List(new KryoSerializeCode())).count()`), then yeah - it would be serialized by Kryo. But for that to work you'll have to make `KryoSerializeCode` a _case class_, or make it `extend Serializable`, because Spark verifies serializability regardless of the custom serializer.